# Trash in WP 3.8?

Tags: trash

For some reason the trash link (to see the trashed posts) is missing, but I'm not sure if it's even supposed to be there in version 3.8.1

We do have the choice to trash an item
[image]

But I can't see where the trash is kept.

This is a heavily modified wordpress site which we can't update unfortunately, but I'm wondering if:
 - Is it even supposed to be there?
 - Can I access it by appending something to the URL? Like /wp-admin/trash.php?

Sorry if it's a silly question, but almost everything online about trash and wordpress is pointing to the hosted version on wordpress.com

I see this in default constants:

```
if ( !defined( 'EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS' ) )
    define( 'EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS', 30 );
```

Comment: Do you have the [`EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS` constant](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Empty_Trash) set in `wp-config.php`? If it's set to `0`, items will be immediately deleted rather than placed in trash.

Comment: thank you, i don't see it in wp-config.php (that file is not there), but I do see something in default_constants file (I updated my question so it's better formatted). What URL do you see when you click "trash"?

Comment: Default constants are the values set if a theme or plugin doesn't set a value first. What do you see if you `echo EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS;` in a template? `trash` is a `post_status`, I'm not sure about v3.8, but something like `/wp-admin/edit.php?post_status=trash` should be the URL for the current version.

Comment: It shows "30" when i echo it, but when I went to /wp-admin/edit.php?post_status=trash it said "No posts found in Trash." But I deleted something less than 30 days ago for sure

Comment: side note: There is no such thing as **we can't** there is only **we don't want**. You are going to run very quickly into a land of pain call "having no one to help you", and if someone thinks upgrading is not fun, being left without any support avenue is even worse

Comment: we can't with the budget we're given, so yeah it's a definite "we can't" lol

Comment: this is usual bean counting. if you upgrade in 6 months than whatever work you are doing now will be just waste of money. Not that I don't understand your situation but you are doing a disservice to whoever you work for if you don't stress the point

Comment: anyway, downvoted and close voted as this is a development oriented site, and not a wordpress usage support. If @otto's answer do not help it is unlikely that anyone will be able to without seeing your code

Comment: k thanks for your useless comments, 0 helpful input whatsoever, wish I could downvote your comments as well

Comment: all i got from you was a bunch of condescending blabber and absolutely 0 value.. and yes you don't know my situation..

Comment: Please even if you don't want to update to a recent version please *at least* upgrade to 3.8.18. This shouldn't really break anything but fixes a tremendous amount of security issues.

Comment: Have you tried dumping the contents of the page? Maybe write a plugin, hook in and dump something in the footer.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have any posts in the Trash, then there won't be a link to go and see them. What would be the point of displaying a link to an empty page, after all?

The link to Trashed posts appears on the All Posts screen at the top, right alongside All | Published | Drafts and so forth. If you want to see it appear, make a new post, and then trash that post so that you actually have something in the trash.

Also, WordPress 3.8 is over 3 years old now. Seriously, just click the update button.

Comment: Making a new post and clicking "Trash" doesn't make link to trashed posts appear